# When I load the data the complete Data Column is getting overwritten

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive, database-partitioning

I tried a simple example in Hadoop which is as follows:

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Empl(EmpID INT,EmpName STRING,SALARY FLOAT)
PARTITIONED BY (DOJ DATE)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Loaded the data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/jugal/Desktop/example' INTO TABLE empl PARTITION(DOJ='2013-04-05');
```

Data in the file:

```
101,Jugal,8000,'2015-04-04'
102,Kannappan,9000,'2015-04-04'
103,Prasanna,10000,'2014-04-01'
104,Hafiez,7000,'2015-04-09'
105,Ashwin,9500,'2013-04-05'
```

Every time I load the partitioned data the complete DOJ column is getting overwritten with the data I partition with.

To my understanding, when data is partitioned depending on a particular date, a directory is created, in which a file is created only with the matching partitioned date given.

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD DATA command only copy the files to the destination directory. It doesn't read the records of the input file, so it cannot do partitioning based on record values.

That is why your record gets overwritten with the static value you mentioned in partition.

In your case , I guess you are looking for dynamic partitioning refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert)

Comment: I tried dynamic partition. The column data is still getting overwritten

Comment: I had made some logical error. THe method u suggested worked well. Thank You